# Placeholder attribute on input tags for IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I know that Internet Explorer doesn't support the placeholder attribute for input tags, but surely in 2012 there must be another solution for IE?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=placeholder+polyfill

Comment: Good question. Before jumping to answer, let's see the situation of *native support* in other browsers. Tested on IE10 RP, -ms-input-placeholder{} psuedo selector supports all the 13 properties [listed on this **test** page](http://newilk.com/testing/Placeholder_styling). Chrome doesn't support padding in placeholder while FF is short of line-height. Newer version of Safari supports 5 out of 13 properties (while 10 properties were supported in its previous version). As of Opera 11, the placeholder styling is dropped.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I wrote a jQuery plugin a while back that will add placeholder support to any browser that does not support it.

[Placeholder Text in IE](http://corymathews.com/html5-placeholder-in-ie/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your code but I can't seem to get it to work. I made a very simple one liner html page to test in in IE 9. here is my code:

Comment: <head>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
 <script src="javascript/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="javascript/placeholder.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $.fn.placeholder();
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form>
            <input id="firstname" type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="e.g. Your Firstname">
  </form>
 </body>

Comment: Anything wrong with what I did. I really tried all sorts of stuff and my links are fine...

Comment: You will need the jQuery document ready function around the function call. $(function() {  $.fn.placeholder(); });

Comment: Thank You Cory. Your solution works well and I really appreciate your willingness to help. You saved me a lot of time and effort. Much thankful

Answer (score 3):

Actually, IE [does support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441188.aspx) the placeholder attribute in 2012 (Version 10). Couple this with [a polyfill](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills) for older browsers, and you should have a well-rounded solution to your problem.

Comment: Instead of using a polyfill you can couple it with the fact that placeholders are not replacements for labels (they are hints and examples), so are non-essential and you can just not worry about browsers that don't support them.

Comment: [html5please.com](http://html5please.com/) is another good resource for this sort of info. On placeholders: [http://html5please.com/#placeholder](http://html5please.com/#placeholder)

Answer (score 0):

We've been using this jQuery plugin in production for a few weeks now and it seems to be working great.

http://webcloud.se/code/jQuery-Placeholder/

Answer (score 0):

http://the.deerchao.net/PlaceHolder
it works on ie without call any function...

Answer (score 0):

Try this jQuery plugin developed by me

https://github.com/ramsunvtech/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/IEPlaceHolder

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a quite easy solution for IE8 and IE9 because on grater versions of IE it already works. (IE10, IE11, etc)

This is the solution i found:

**1. Detect Internet Explorer version**

```
<!--[if lt IE 10]>       
    <script type="text/javascript">var ie = 9;</script>      
<![endif]-->     
<!--[if lt IE 9]>                   
    <script type="text/javascript">var ie = 8;</script>          
<![endif]-->
```

**2. Fix the placeholder**

```
if (typeof ie == 'undefined') var ie = 10;   
if (ie == 8 || ie == 9){  

    $("input[placeholder]").each(function() {
        this.value = $(this).attr('placeholder');
    });        

    $("input[placeholder]").focus(function() 
        if (this.value == $(this).attr('placeholder')) this.value = '';
    }).blur(function() {   
        if (this.value == '')
            this.value = $(this).attr('placeholder'); 
    });
}
```