# Logic behind HTML5 Placeholder

Tags: jquery, html

I am working with a form. Each input field name is identified by its Placeholder. My form working fine in Chrome and Mozilla but fail in IE7 and IE8 because these browser does not support Placeholder attributes of HTML5.

My form is divided into 4 parts. When user fills the first part and click on save and proceed a trigger is fired on database and it shows second part of form and so on

**To achieve placeholder in IE , I have tried various plugins and i also create one of my own but everything fails because the placeholder values save in database if i leave the field blank.**

HTML5 placeholder worked fine for me in chrome. So if anyone can provide me the logic of HTML5 placeholder i will write it down in jquery to get a same functionality in IE.

Comment: If the value of input is the same of default value (placeholder), don't send it. If value of input equal empty string, set value of input as placeholder one. Honestly, you shouldn't try to implement placeholder for browsers which don't support it, just use classic labels instead.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335610/placeholder-attribute-on-input-tags-for-ie

Comment: @roasted I've chosen to ignore IE completely, but if you want to support it, roasted's method is your best solution IMO.

Comment: i already implemented that but my placeholder values are getting saved on save and proceed button click.

Comment: I think the placeholder text is part of browser UI, not the "value" of the input. If you really want to have this in IE 8, and don't mind to go a little complicate, you can emulate it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zcuah/

Comment: @Passerby: Great..this logic can work..thanks..i am working around it now..

Answer (score 0):

You can make a jquery function, that initializes the value of the input to some text when the document is loaded (this should be your placeholder) and then put this value to "" (nothing) when there is an onclick event in the input. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FXsRg/3/).

`_selector` is a custom variable that I've made. Just change the line to the ID of whatever field you want to put this placeholder on. You can chance the `_placeholder` to contain whatever placeholder text you want inside the field :).

I just change the css and html properties of the input field on when the user clicks inside it (or outside).

One problem with this technique is that when you post the form, it will think the value's are set (since the value is _placeholder (or "Address" in this example). Your best bet would be to check if the value is equal to your placeholder in the PHP script. If it is you can just tell your script to use "" instead of the var.

Answer (score 0):

Going with @Hamdi, you can try jQuery. [This](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-html5-placeholder-text) is a very good article for that.