# CSS to display form field

Tags: html, css

I have created the an HTML form and I want to assign the values with CSS to the input fields not by `value="Email"` I have an ID assigned to each field and I want to use that ID and assign the values to the field.
The cod for the form is given. Please help me in this case, I will be thankful

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook Add PHP Example</title>
<style type="text/css">
#formwrapper{
width:340px;
border:0;
background-color:#dce37f;
margin: 70px auto;
padding: 20px 0;
display:block;
}

form {
display:block;
width:340px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.text{
width: 275px;
border-radius:6px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
background:#fcfcfc;
border:3px solid #cccccc;
box-shadow:0px 0px 3px 1px #cccccc;
outline: none;
padding:10px;
margin: 10px 10px 10px 18.5px;
}
.text:focus{
background:#e6edfc;
border:3px solid #deb93e;
box-shadow:0px 0px 3px 1px #cccccc;
}
.fname{
display: inline;
width: 116px;
border-radius:6px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
background:#fcfcfc;
border:3px solid #cccccc;
box-shadow:0px 0px 3px 1px #cccccc;
outline: none;
padding:10px;
margin: 10px 10px 10px 18.5px;
}
.fname:focus{
background:#e6edfc;
border:3px solid #deb93e;
box-shadow:0px 0px 3px 1px #cccccc;
}
.lname{
display: inline;
width: 116px;
border-radius:6px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
background:#fcfcfc;
border:3px solid #cccccc;
box-shadow:0px 0px 3px 1px #cccccc;
outline: none;
padding:10px;
margin: 10px 10px 10px 1px;
}
.lname:focus{
background:#e6edfc;
border:3px solid #deb93e;
box-shadow:0px 0px 3px 1px #cccccc;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

</script>

</head>
<body class="body">
<div id="mainwrapper">
<div id="formwrapper">
<div id="content_image4" class="ss_box_content ss_image_content">
<img class="no_hotspots" src="original_hembakat_besta_ll.png" />
</div>
<form id="demo-form">

    <input type="email" name="email" id="Email" parsley-trigger="change" required class="text" /><br/>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id= "Fornamn" required size="18px" class="fname" />
     <input type="text" name="lastname" id= "Efternamn" required size="18px" class="lname" /><br/>
     <center><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" /></center>
     </div>

</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried? What happened? What code did you use? Provide your code in the question and add a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: I edit the code, hope you will understand what I want

Comment: What is the specific problem?

Comment: The problem is that I got job offer and they used ShortStock.com to design faceebook app. But in ShotStock I can not assign the values to the form field, like we assigned normally. and I can not do this by javascript because I have only CSS option. I want to display the values of each field by css. In form input field I have no option to assign value=this I have only id and I want to use that ID in CSS to  assign the value to the field.

Comment: This is my form, http://mrprofessional.se/facebook/index2.php

Comment: Oh, so you want to set default values to the input elements?

Comment: yes, and I want to use use the each field ID like for email I have id="Email", and with CSS assing the value to the field. So I will display in the field and when some body click inside the field then I will disappear. I done all the job but only this one task is remaining and I am confuse

Comment: I found the solution of the problem for fields, and it s only possible by JavaScript. I used your JavaScript Idea and the problem are now solve. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input placeholder="This grey text will be deleted if the user clicks on the input" />
```

You can see support [here](http://caniuse.com/input-placeholder), make it work for IE lte 9 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335610/placeholder-attribute-on-input-tags-for-ie), and see the spec [here](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-placeholder-attribute).

Comment: yes this is true, but I actually designing this form in ShortStack.com database, and I have no option to Assign the value or placeholder to the input field. In the input field I have only this given attributes <input type="email" name="email" id="Email" parsley-trigger="change" required class="text" /> and I have CSS control, I want to use either the class or Id to assign the values to the fields.

Comment: there is only CSS Editor,, that kind of editor that we use in wordpress and the interface is same like wordpress. u will the the CSS box and will write the css and it will do changes, I will tray the sripts too, but I can see only css box. i am not sure that in this box I gona use scripts

Comment: If you can't use script or placeholder, then you're outta luck.

Comment: OK but if we use script for that, then what scripts will work with that?? Actually my assignment is to design this kind of form and page https://www.facebook.com/Hembakat/app_1422281951321099

Comment: how I can do this with Java Script?

Comment: I found the solution of the problem for fields, and it s only possible by JavaScript. I used your JavaScript Idea and the problem are now solve. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer....
Using for labels

```
#Email:before {
   content: "Email address: ";
}
#Fornamn:before {
   content: "Email address: ";
}
#Efternamn:before {
   content: "Email address: ";
}
```

for placeholder

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder::beforeor ::-webkit-input-placeholder::after
```

Unfortunately to add more placeholder content doesn't work anymore. Think its a new Chrome update.