# Input placeholder for IE not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, input

I have a bit of a problem. My signup page is dark and the input's on the page are also dark (with shading contrasts). I don't have labels for the input's because I have placeholder text that's a lighter color which is very visible. Unfortunately, today I discovered that on Internet Explorer 10 and earlier, the placeholders aren't there so anyone who has that browser would just have to guess what the inputs are for. Is there anything I can do or a hack around this??

Thanks so much.

Comment: Ehm, placeholder works fine in IE10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a really good jQuery plugin that should be what you're after:https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder. Once setup, this plugin will enable you to just use the placeholder attribute as you normally would.

Comment: Not sure why you're being downvoted...if OP needs/wants placeholders in earlier IE Javascript is the only possible solution. Here are 10+ libraries: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills#web-forms--input-placeholder

Comment: @Benjamin - thanks, that's a useful link. I think someone on SO is doing a few rounds of drive-by downranking. Guess someone is happy that they've got enough rep to do so :)

Comment: @wickywills, that solution didn't work for IE 10.(and no i didn't downvote yours either lol). I uploaded the js file and then activated it for inputs and textareas but the placeholder text isn't working. Did i do something wrong?

Comment: @Justin - should work fine. I have sites that use it and it works down to IE6 I think. Do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: No, that's the first thing I checked and didn't have errors. If you say it works on yours then obviously something I'm doing isn't working. I'll keep looking at it. What sucks is I'm on a Mac so I have to "trial and error test it" and change something, then push to Heroku, then call my wife to see if her work computer IE works haha. Might be a long morning. Seems like both you and @Benjamin are correct so I'll acccept your answers! Thank you both

Comment: @Justin - Not a problem. Do you have a link to your site? Could give it a go here if you want?

Comment: https://www.themoderntrunk.com/signup . I may just add labels as a temporary fix until I can get in front of a computer that has IE to better test.

Comment: @Justin - Sorry, I don't actually have IE10 on this computer (dodgy old work laptop) - works perfectly in IE9 though! Will check in IE10 when I get home

Comment: Should get yourself a copy of Virtualbox / Parallels / VMWare Fusion and stick a copy of Windows on it with IE tester. That's what I do when I'm stuck (though I have a 8.1 laptop to play with as well). You can get some virtual machine images from [modern.ie](http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools) :)

Comment: Awesome thanks for the testing wickywillis and the tip @stckrboy

Comment: @Justin, I have a few VMs and a BrowserStack subscription...do you still have a page up somewhere with placeholders and the library that I can check?

Comment: Unfortunately I just changed it to labels instead. We launched yesterday so I just couldn't chance it if ya get me. I really appreciate all y'alls help though.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `<label>` next to the input. If the user can't tell what they should be entering into the field if the placeholder doesn't show up, then it isn't an appropriate use of the placeholder.

From [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-placeholder-attribute):

> The placeholder attribute represents a short hint (a word or short
>   phrase) intended to aid the user with data entry when the control has
>   no value. A hint could be a sample value or a brief description of the
>   expected format. [...]
>
> The placeholder attribute should not be used as a replacement for a
>   label

Comment: For design/UI purposes a label on this page wouldn't look good

Comment: Always nice to see looking good prioritised over working well or being correct.

Comment: +1 - this is good info related to the original question. Unsure why you were downvoted...

Answer (score 0):

Placeholder is supported in IE10 but not below ([Can I use Placeholder](http://caniuse.com/input-placeholder))

> Is there anything I can do or a hack around this??

If you have to have placeholders then you will need to go down the JavaScript route.  There are many examples of this on SO, here are a couple.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10337071/1593273

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19312280/1593273

As [Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin) has said, if the information that you are displaying is important and must be visible to all users (this includes screen readers too), then your implementation is not correct and should be re-thought.

If the browsers you are supporting have no support for placeholders then they are merely an enhancement and should not be depended on.